# ActionBar icon is not showing if setDisplayHomeEnabled is false

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to set icon on ActionBar. 
So when I have setDisplayShowHomeEnabled set to true icon shows, when false - nothing. I don't want show back button on actionBar, only icon. 
What's the problem?

```
            actionBar.setTitle("");
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_big));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For <kbd>Back</kbd> button write this code:

```java
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

It's by default false though, but in your case if it's showing, then you have to set it to false programatically.

You have to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. actionbar object was initialized previously by getSupportActionBar(). I just didn't paste that part